# how to find a file path of a particular file in program folder c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a requirement to find the path of a particular file.
I know the file name and extension of the file. but i don't know where the file resides.
The file will in any of the sub directories of **C:\Program Files**. so i need to search inside the program folder for the file.
My file name is **CASdb.accdb**

Comment: Ok, great! What part of that are you having a problem with? Have you tried anything? What if there are two of them?

Comment: string[] filePaths = System.IO. Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Program Files","CASdb.accdb",SearchOption.AllDirectories); But it take too much time to search. is there any other good method

Answer (score 3):

One of the fastest ways is to **enumerate** over the files in the directory. Granted, in *C:\Program Files* there will be a lot of files, so you'd have to test this out to see how well it performs.

[MSDN - Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458.aspx)

An example:

```
// LINQ query for all files containing the word 'Europe'. 
var files = from file in 
    Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\\Program Files\\", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        where file.ToLower().Contains("casdb.accdb")
        select file;
```

Comment: Given the low number of files returned; `EnumerateFiles` isn't going to buy you much. I'm also not sure that does a recursive search. Check that; it will, but you need a different overload.

Comment: Thanks @BradleyDotNET for your input. Haven't had occasion to use it myself but figured it would be kind of fast. My first thought, honestly, was to tap into the Windows Search Index. Maybe that's a possibility? (given that the directory is indexed, which I'm not sure by default if it is)

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` will lazy iterate the query; which is great if you only want the first 20 of 10000. But it will still have to search everything to get the first one, so unless it finds it fast, its still doing a lot of enumeration. That said; it is the right option. If you edit to contain the correct overload, I'd give you a +1.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Added `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to overload method. Is that what you're looking for? :) I mistakenly thought the default option was recursive.

Comment: Yep, thats the one I saw. You also need a search pattern argument, but you can have my +1 anyways; I'm sure you'll fix it. :)

Comment: i am not getting the result it showing the message "Enumeration yielded no results"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles` to find files in **ProgramFiles** folder.

```
// Search All Files **Recursive**
DirSearch(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles));
files.Dump();

// Search Files in ProgramFiles Folder Only
files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)));
files.AddRange(Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)));

static List<string> files = new List<string>();
static void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
  try
  {
      foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
      {
          foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d))
          {
              if (true /*logic*/)
                  files.Add(f);
          }
          DirSearch(d);
      }
  }
  catch (System.Exception excpt)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
  }
}
```

you should implement search logic in `foreach`.